# Search for field in a List of Objects in Java

Tags: java

In an application I'm designing I have a list of custom Objects called `Shop`. The Shop class can be seen here.

#### Shop.java

```
public class Shop extends Object {

    private String title = "";
    private List<HashMap<String, String>> branchDetails = new ArrayList<>();
    private String description = "";
    private String imageLink = "";
    private String webLink = "";

    public Shop() {

    }
}
```

In my application I create a `List<Shop>` object and populate it with 1500 Shop objects.

Now I would like to search through the List and find the index of a Shop with a "Weblink" that matches a string. i.e. I would like to query the List the same way you would a Database. Is there a way to do this without having to build and populate a Database?

I have overridden the equals and hashcode methods in Shop.java and can use the [List#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method to verify the list contains a object with a matching weblink but cannot get the index of that object.

The equals and hashcode methods:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Shop shop = (Shop) o;

    return getWebLink().equals(shop.getWebLink());

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return getWebLink().hashCode();
}
```

To use this I create a new shop with webLink I would like to query

```
Shop shop = new Shop();
shop.setWebLink("http://somelink.com");

shopsList.contains(shop) //returns true if weblink string matches one from list of shops
```

Comment: While allowing an equals check like the question suggests can work, what happens when you then wish to "search" by title, or description? Overriding the .equals as shown is potentially limiting.

Comment: Yes, I agree it is limiting and perhaps not very scalable but for my needs currently, the weblink is all I need to match. It's kind of link a unique identifier.

Comment: Note, in this case, you want `indexOf` instead of `contains` but the idea is exactly the same.

Comment: Maybe you should just use a map like this:  Map<String, Integer> linkMap = new HashMap<>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the method indexOf of the Collections API, it's what you're looking for.

Comment: As far as I know, indexOf requires the whole object to match. So in this case it would return -1. Or am I mistaken? Does indexOf call the overridden equals method when determining the index?

Comment: Yes it uses the overriden equals method, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29.

Comment: Holy Cow so it does. I tested the indexOf method already but that must have been before I created the new equals method. Thank you sir that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

use `indexOf()` to get the element index.

Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.

Be aware, if you have multiple meaningful equality shops, it returns the first match index.

Comment: As far as I know, indexOf requires the whole object to match. So in this case it would return -1. Or am I mistaken? Does indexOf call the overridden equals method when determining the index?

Comment: you can create a `Shop` instance based on your String `webLink`, and checks the instance in List or not, right?